# Переполнение стека из-за статического конструктора

Tags: c#

У меня есть `Timer`, который по определенным причинам я проинициализировал в статическом конструкторе. После того как я добавил этот статический конструктор, при создании экземпляров других классов в обычном конструкторе выдает `Stack overflow exception`. Почему это происходит.

```
class TimerData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    static TimerData()
    {           
        timer = new Timer(1000);
    }

    public TimerData()
    {
        // Stack overflow exception
        timer.Elapsed += TimerTick;
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        EventSecondsNotify += UpdateTime;

        // Ошибка возникает после добавления этой строки
        parameters = new Parameters();
    }

    private static Timer timer;
    private Parameters parameters;
}
```

**Edit 1**
Причина Stack overflow exception

```
class A
{
    public A()
    {
        b = new B();
    }

    B b;
}

class B
{
    public B()
    {
        a = new A();
    }

    A a;
}
```

**Edit 2** как вызвать конструктор с параметрами?

```
public class TimerData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public TimerData()
    {
        //parameters = new Parameters();
    }

    public TimerData(Parameters pr = null)
    {
        parameters = pr ?? new Parameters(this);
    }

    // Создаю экземпляр класса TimerData, чтобы через него вызвать
    // конструктор с параметрами. Выдает ошибку, что инициализатор
    // поля не может обращаться к нестатическому полю
    TimerData timerData = new TimerData();
    private Parameters parameters = new Parameters(timerData);
}


public class Parameters : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Parameters()
    {
        //timerData = new TimerData();
        //timerData.EventSecondsNotify += DecreaseFatigue;
        //timerData.EventSecondsNotify += DecreaseSatiety;
    }

    // Как вызвать этот конструктор?
    public Parameters(TimerData td = null)
    {
        timerData = td ?? new TimerData(this);
        timerData.EventSecondsNotify += DecreaseFatigue;
        timerData.EventSecondsNotify += DecreaseSatiety;
    }

    private TimerData timerData;
```

}

Comment: Ну так если ошибка после добавления строки с классом Parameters, то наверное в этом классе Parameters и нужно смотреть, а не в TimerData

Comment: Конструктор оказался не при чем. Причина в обновленном коде. А как в этом случае можно избежать ошибки, если нужно, чтоб классы видели друг-друга?

Comment: Передавать ссылку на объект класса А в конструктор класса В

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас получается бесконечное создание экземпляров классов `A` and `B`.

**Пояснение:**

Когда вызывается конструктор класса `A`, создается объект класса `B`, у класса `B`, создается класс `A`, и так далее по кругу до бесконечности. Поэтому происходит переполнение.

Избавлением от этого может стать, передача ссылки классу `B`, на класс `A`, или наоборот.

```
public class A
{
    B b;

    public A(B classB = null)
    {
        b = classB ?? new B(this);
    }
}

public class B
{
    A a;

    public B(A classA = null)
    {
        a = classA ?? new A(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Подскажите, как вызвать конструктор с параметрами? Обновил код в Eidt 2